# How to create a table to a specific user

Tags: mysql

First good evening every body.
assume that you are logged in as a super user and you want to create a user.

```
  CREATE USER 'user1'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH 'mysql_native_password' AS '*483EC567DF968A6AD5E279257828E7CC4A12F0C2' REQUIRE NONE PASSWORD EXPIRE DEFAULT ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

and you want to create some tables for that user something like this

```
CREATE TABLE user1.user1Table -- table for user1  
(
idUser INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name VARCHAR(30)
) ENGINE=INNODB ;
```

when I run the sql script I get an error like this

```
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'user1'
```

I thought at the beginning that I would have something like that

```
mysql> desc user1Table ;
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| idUser | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name   | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

**why that is not possible ??? i have wamp server**

thank you in advance

Comment: Although this is MySQL and not SQL Server, let me assist you in getting a better answer.  First, what happens when you run those above queries? Do you get an error (and if so, what is the error?), a different resultset than you expect, nothing, a quarter-pound of Milk Duds (in which case, please specify your *EXACT* setup), or ????

Comment: i did it @LaughingVergil

Comment: Have you considered first creating a _database_ in which the table will reside, as the error message implies?

Comment: create a database for the user (CREATE DATABASE) and give the user all access to just that database.

Comment: i already have a database what i want is that the super user (admin) create the table for user1 and when i login as user1 i i want to see the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL `CREATE TABLE` syntax, the statement

```
CREATE TABLE user1.user1Table
```

… attempts to create the table user1Table **in the database user1**. The value before the period in that create statement is the database name, not anything related to the user account that the table is created under.

To limit the information accessible to a user, you are going to have to play with permissions. This will not do what you apparently think it should.

Comment: so what i want is not possible :(

Comment: The `CREATE DATABASE` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE TABLE {database}.{tablename}`

creates a table in the specified database. As such you'll need a user only table
`CREATE TABLE user1Table...`

To give a user access to the table:

`GRANT ALL ON {database}.user1Table TO 'user1'@'%'`

Where {database} is the database in which the tables are created.

Comment: ```CREATE TABLE c##libraire1.categories (
 idCategorie INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 libCategorie VARCHAR(30) 
 );
/``` with oracle database it work so why it doesn't work on mysql

Answer (score 0):

`root` needs to allow `user1` into the system, at least into one database:

```
CREATE USER user1 ...;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db1.* TO user1@'%';
```

`root` needs to give the user a database to work in:

```
CREATE DATABASE db1;
```

The user needs to login and to go into that database:

```
USE db1;
CREATE TABLE user1Table (...)...;
```